# Long Line Marker: Visual Studio 2010 EXPRESS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express, visual-c++-2010

I'd like to have long line marker in my Visual C++ 2010 Express.
I've tried almost every possible combination of the regedit->guides trick and none of them worked (It works fine with 2008 Express, but it seems to be no longer supported with 2010 Express).
I have also tried many different plugins, but they don't work with 2010 either.

Any tips?
Thanks.

Comment: No, the Express editions don't support plug-ins. I assume you've tried the method described [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0fbf2878-e678-4577-9fdb-9030389b338c/)? I don't have Express installed, so I can't test if it still works. But it works fine in the full versions, so I can't imagine why it would be broken in Express.

Comment: @Cody-Gray: Yes, I did. With no luck...